# <fileset> doesn't support nested "fileset" error in Apache Ant

Tags: ant

Let me explain the scenario.

Directory A has 10 folders.

Directory B has 20 folders.

So: Folders in A + 10 folders = Folders in B.
and A is not child of B, its an independent folder located else where.

I have written a program in Apache Ant that copies the unique 10 folders of B(which are not present in A) to Directory C. My build.xml is below.

```
<project name="MyTask" basedir="." default="target">
    <target name="target">
        <copy todir="C">
            <fileset dir="B">
                <include name="**.*"/>
                <fileset refid="excludeFilesFromA"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <fileset id="excludeFilesFromA" dir="A">
        <exclude name="**.*"/>
    </fileset>
</project>
```

The Ant script is throwing an exception:

> fileset doesn't support the nested "fileset" element.

Could you guide me to the right way to fix this.

Comment: Is `A` a child directory of `B`? If it's not, just remove the `<fileset refid="excludeFilesFromA"/>` line.

Comment: The question has been edited,which totally altered the meaning..  Directory A has 10 folders.

Directory B has 20 folders.

So: Folders in A + 10 folders = Folders in B. and A is not child of B, its an independent folder located else where.

I have written a program in Apache Ant that copies the unique 10 folders of B

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?
I'm having the same error.